# JList like tree

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jtree

I've got 1 `JList` using 4 Models. The list shows model depending on which one user chose from `JComboBox`. What I currently have is that list shows data for all models like this:

```
group1
group2
group3
...
```

What I need is that for 3 models it shows like that (above), but for other one it have to show like this (tree structure):

```
group1
      group1_0
      group1_1
group2
group3
      group3_0
...
```

Can anyone help me with this? Can anyone point me to some implementation of this or (what else I found is) should I depending on value from `JComboBox` 'switch' between `JList` and `JTree`? And how would I do that without messing with layout (I am using `GridBagLayout`).

Comment: Well, you'd better have a JList when you need a list and a JTree when you need a tree, seems pretty logical

Comment: You might be able to use a custom `ListCellRenderer` and some HTML or `EmptyBorder` to force the spacing, but I agree with Dici, if you have nail, don't use a screw driver ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should I depending on value from JComboBox 'switch' between JList and JTree?

Yes.  Unless you can think of a better way.

> And how would I do that without messing with layout(I am using GridBagLayout)

Put a panel where the list is now.  Give the panel a `CardLayout`<sup>1</sup>.  Add the `JTree` and `JList` to the panel and flip between them as needed.

1. E.G. as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).